# Typescript errors after including all TypeScript files in .csproj

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm upgrading an AngularJS app to Angular, and I've created a hybrid AngularJS/Angular project that's using TypeScript 2.6.2. (It essentially works by loading AngularJS through an Angular bootstrap method, using SystemJS for the module loading).

It compiles without errors when I run node installed TypeScript from the Windows command line using:

```
npm run tsc
```

When I first tried building the project in Visual Studio 2015, the TypeScript didn't transpile to JavaScript, so I've tried adding the following to the .csproj file (there were previously no instructions to include TypeScript files):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="**\*.ts" />
```

Now I get the following build errors:

[image]

My project structure is like this:

[image]

And my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true
  },
  "include": [ "**/*.ts" ]
}
```

What could be going on and what might I do to get the project building successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the reason my project wasn't building successfully through Visual Studio is that I needed to include my tsconfig.json file in the solution. That causes Visual Studio to ignore the TypeScript configuration in the .csproj file and use tsconfig.json instead

I had to unload and re-load the project a few times, saving in between, until the VS2015 project properties were recognised by Visual Studio as being disabled. Closing and re-opening Visual Studio, saving any changes to the project if prompted, would probably achieve the same thing:

[image]

The project now builds without having to use:

```
<TypeScriptCompile Include="**\*.ts" />
```

and I no longer have any errors in the solution.

(I also installed and uninstalled the 'TypeScript Compiler' using the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio, although I'm unsure if this had any effect, since I'd already installed the TypeScript Build Tools for VS2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)